# What's difference between these two statements?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

The question seems easy but i couldn't find any answer. So, what's the difference between `int Array[10]` and `array<int, 10> Array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ there are numerous ways to create arrays. `int Array[10];` will create an array similar to a C array. This means that there are a lot of memory problems inherent to it. `array<int, 10> Array;` is C++ wrapping of the former array and removes the memory problems. Additionally, the C++ version is more adept in doing iteration, bounds checking, and a few other minor features. While they both will do the same thing in the end, unless you are doing something which specifically requires a C array I would go with the C++ and it will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: You may like to elaborate on _lot of memory problems_.

Answer (score 0):

`int Array[10]` is a c-style array declaration which raw memory and if you want to operate on the array you will have to write your own functions.

`array<int, 10> Array` is a C++ style array declaration using the [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) class which is an `STL container`.

The later provides a lot of predefined methods to operate on the array, for example to find out how many elements are there in the array, you just need to say `Array.size()`. However in case of the former you may have to write your own function to iterate over the array to find out the size.